# Replace elements in python array where conditions are based on position in the array

Tags: python

So I was wondering of a pythonic way of doing this computation. I have a 2D `numpy` array with all zeros. Now depending on the co-ordinate I want to fill some values in it. To be specific let us say we have 2 integers `(a,b)`, then in the array I want to fill each place with `max(abs(index1-a), abs(index2-b))`.

I was thinking of some way to solve this in a single line like, for example if we want to replace all negative elements with 0 then:

`array[array<0] = 0`

Any tips on how to solve it in a single line? I am not looking for single line loops or lambda expressions.

Comment: so the result should be `m[i, j] = max(i, j)`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no (a,b) is fixed while index1 and index2 are the position of the element in the array I am looking at....to be specific the array is currently filled with zero's..now I want to fill it based on the current condition

Comment: And `index1`, and `index2` are the "indices" of the matrix for that element, right?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes

Comment: I don't know if that helps, but I would do some analysis on the function `f(a,b) = max(abs(index1-a), abs(index2-b))` and try to find a way to predict the results for all indexes. For example, it seems like the function has a minimum in (index1=a,index2=b), where it corresponds to zero, and that from there for each increment of ±1 of one or both of the variables, f(a±1,b)=f(a,b±1)= f(a,b)+1. Edit: i mixed (index1,index2) with (a,b), but the result is the same given the abs()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can *design* such matrix with:

```
a = 3  # sample a
b = 5  # sample b
arr = np.zeros((10, 7))  # sample zeros
m, n = arr.shape
arr[:,:] = np.maximum(np.arange(m).reshape(-1,1) - a, np.arange(n) - b)
```

But if you do not need to *modify* the matrix itself, we can simply construct a new one (with `arr = np.maximum(..)`).

For a 10×7 matrix with `a = 3`, and `b = 5`, we then obtain:

```
>>> arr
array([[-3., -3., -3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-2., -2., -2., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.,  6.]])
```

**EDIT**: if we want *absolute values* `np.abs(..)`:

```
arr[:,:] = np.maximum(np.abs(np.arange(m).reshape(-1,1) - a), np.abs(np.arange(n) - b))
```

then the result is:

```
>>> arr
array([[5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]])
```

**Performance**

We defined two functions `f` and `g`:

```
>>> def f():
...   a, b = 3, 5
...   m, n = 10, 7
...   arr = np.zeros((m, n))
...   arr[:,:] = np.maximum(np.arange(m).reshape(-1,1) - a, np.arange(n) - b)
...
>>> def g():
...   a, b = 3, 5
...   m, n = 10, 7
...   arr = np.zeros((m, n))
...   i, j = np.indices((m, n))
...   arr[:,:] = np.maximum(np.abs(i - a), np.abs(j - b))
```

then we run both functions 1'000'000 times:

```
>>> timeit(f, number=1000000)
7.471106000011787
>>> timeit(g, number=1000000)
18.07209299999522
```

We also ran it 1'000 times for an 1000×700 matrix:

```
>>> timeit(f, number=1000)
2.5362389999936568
>>> timeit(g, number=1000)
43.055561000001035
```

My hypothesis for this "performance gap" is that the `np.indices()` creates a 2×m×n matrix, which thus allocates a similar amount of memory. By constructing two 1d arrays, we take linear time in the intermediate matrices, and make use of broadcasting to calculate the elements of the final matrix.

Comment: How is it giving those zeros though?

Comment: @DuttaA: well that is where the column index is `5`, and the row index is `3`, since then `max(i-3, j-5)` is `0`, since if `i` is smaller, but `j=5`, then the result is `5`, and the same for the transpose.

Comment: You are technically correct...it is a mistake in my question, I actually wanted the positive distance..that means `mod(index1-a)`..sorry my bad..your answer is quite nice

Comment: Well then you should wrap it within `np.abs(..)`

Comment: but the 0's will remain 0's, ..I modified my question

Comment: @DuttaA: but `mod(..)` itself makes no sense, one needs a divisor.

Comment: by mod i mean absoluteor `abs` in computer language

Comment: Let's s see some other answers..i'll accept ur answer after some time if no other answer comes

Comment: only one thing better that can possibly be done is .reshape(-1, 1)

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.indices` + `np.maximum`:

```
a, b = 3, 5
i, j = np.indices((10, 7))
np.maximum(np.abs(i - a), np.abs(j - b)))

array([[5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1],
       [5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]])
```

`np.indices` return the row and column indices as a 2D matrix; no reshaping required.

Comment: @DuttaA This answer was written based on the discussion under the other answer.

Comment: Check the array provided by the other user...I want something like that

Comment: @DuttaA Okay, that should fix it